# Creating album for mysql and php online photo album

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am creating a mysql backed online photo album and using php to access my mysql database, I am having trouble trying to create a form that lets users create a new album, so far i have the following code:

```
<h1>My Photo Collection</h1>
<h3>Add, search and  browse through our collection!</h3>
<section id="collection">
<h4>Create Album</h4>
<form method='post'>
        <?php
        require_once 'config.php'; 
        $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if(isset($_POST['title'])){
        $name = $_POST['title'];
        if(empty($name)){ 
            echo "Please enter album name <br/>";
        } else{
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO albums VALUES('', '$title')");
            echo "Album was successfully created <br/>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    Album Name: <input type="text" name="title" /> <input type="submit" value="create" />
</form>
</section>
```

My schema for the ' albums' table is: 
title, date_created, date_modified (time stamp), albumID (primary key)

Further questions:
how do I allow a user to enter a date no the form (and make sure it is in the correct format), how does the date_modified timestamp work (do I need to put it in the form?)

I am using mysqli and not mysql in my php queries.
So far, my code returns "undefined object 'title'" 
Can anyone help me and figure out what I'm doing wrong with my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `$title` is undefined, you assigned `$_POST['title']` to `$name`. And since you're using MySQLi API, use prepared statements instead.

As for the date, just use `NOW()`

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php'; 
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['title'])) {
        echo 'Please enter album name <br/>';
    } else {
        $name = $_POST['title'];
        $insert = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO albums (title, date_created, date_modified) VALUES(?, NOW(), NOW())') or die($mysqli->error);
        $insert->bind_param('s', $name);
        if($insert->execute()) {
            echo 'Album was successfully created <br/>';
        } else {
            echo $mysqli->error;
        }

    }
}

?>

<h1>My Photo Collection</h1>
<h3>Add, search and  browse through our collection!</h3>
<section id="collection">
    <h4>Create Album</h4>
    <form method='post'>
        Album Name: <input type="text" name="title" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="create" />
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: @mar oh okay, its supposed to be `$insert->bind_param('s', $name);` with one `s` only

Comment: @mar it should be `$insert->execute()` should work just fine now